# Substituting Value for Independent Random Variable in Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence, expected-value

- Let $\tilde{D}$ be a topological space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\tilde{D})$,
- $\tilde{g}: \Omega \times \tilde{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded $(\mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\tilde{D}) ) / \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function,
- $\tilde{\Pi}: \Omega \rightarrow \tilde{D}$ be a $\mathcal{G}/\mathcal{B}(\tilde{D})$-measurable random variable,
- $\tilde{Y} : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathcal{G}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable random variable, defined by $\tilde{Y}(\omega) := \tilde{g}(\omega, \tilde{\Pi}(\omega))$,
- $\tilde{s}: \tilde{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{P}) $ be defined by $\tilde{s}(\pi)(\omega) := \tilde{g}(\omega, \pi)$,
- $\tilde{E} : \tilde{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $\tilde{E}(\pi) = \mathbb{E}[\tilde{s}(\pi)]$, and
- for all $\pi \in \tilde{D}$, let $\tilde{s}(\pi)$ be independent of $\tilde{\Pi}$.

In this setting, I want to prove the following statement:

$\tilde{E}$ is $\mathcal{B}(\tilde{D})/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable and $ \tilde{E} \circ \tilde{\Pi}$ is a version of the $\mathbb{P}$-unique conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{Y} \mid \tilde{\Pi}]$.

Is this even true? An idea for a proof would be fantastic!

Comment: This is essentially the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3206814/11867, except $j$ became $s$, tildes were added, and you have rephrased the conjecture according to my earlier suggestion. I suspect this violates some policy about duplicate questions, and the better approach would be to edit your earlier question and clarify what you would still like to know, which is not covered by the answers already given.

Comment: Or, if you are wanting to follow the steps I suggested in my other answer, I believe you could post separate questions about individual steps. For example, you could post a question about how to prove that $g$ and $\Pi$ are independent. Or you could post a question about how to prove that the function $\Phi$ in my answer is measurable. Or you could post questions about the relevant theorems in the notes I linked. And so on.

Comment: There seems to be a hole in your argumentation, see my comments  on   math.stackexchange.com/q/3206814/11867

Kind Regards

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will respond over there. But this one should probably be flagged as a duplicate.